# How to ssr to replace all string in kdb?

Tags: kdb

table dd

```
dd:([]a:("account=abcde;cash=123";"account=abc;cash=345");1 2)
```

result:

```
"account=abcde;cash=123"    1
"account=abc;cash=345"      2
```

I want to replace everything in account: 
so the result should be

```
"replace;cash=123"  1
"replace;cash=345"  2
```

I tried this

```
update ssr[;"account=* ;";""] each a from dd
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
q)update {";"sv @[s;where (s:";"vs x) like "account=*";:;enlist"newVal=123"]}each a from dd
```

Answer (score 2):

And just to throw one more answer on the pile!  If you can assume the account part you want to replace is always the first member of the ; separated list you can use the slightly simpler:

```
update ";"sv'@[;0;:;"replace"]each";"vs'a from dd
```

Answer (score 1):

can't use wild card * with ssr information on http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/regex/#regex-in-q
for integrating with regex libraries.

alternative solution to ssr:

```
update a:{v:(" *";";")0:x;y,/:v 0}[a;"replacestring;"] from dd where a like "account=\*"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following if you want to explicitly use `ssr`:

```
update {ssr[first "=" vs x;"account";"replace",";",last ";" vs x]} each a from dd

a                  x
--------------------
"replace;cash=123" 1
"replace;cash=345" 2
```

Comment: Would only support 2 key/value pairs:
dd:([]a:("account=abcde;id=112234;cash=123";"account=abc;id=112236;cash=345");1 2)